# Portable QR Code (QRcode) generation app for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, portable, qr-code

Please recommend a simple QR Code generation app with the following features:

- Portable (no installation)
- Gratis (free of cost)
- Windows compatible
- Completely offline (does not attempt internet access)

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "*a simple [...] app*"? - a stripped down GUI? light on resources? qr-generation only via plain text?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Something that *simply* generates a QR Code from a string.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve been using **Zint Barcode Studio**, it handles 50 different barcode formats including QRcode(2008), open source and portable (will exe from USB stick)!

http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/zint

http://zint.org.uk/Manual.aspx?type=p&page=1

Download from **Sourceforge**, unzip file to a folder and create shortcut to **qtzint.exe**, double click shortcut to run. ***I hope this Helps!***

Comment: Wow!  That looks powerful.  Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinPython + a couple of libraries to get what you need with the following steps:

1. Download [WinPython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/), (in this case I would recommend a [32 bit zero edition](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_3.6/3.6.1.0/WinPython-32bit-3.6.1.0Zero.exe/download) as that is a lot smaller and should work on **any** windows machine).
2. Run the downloaded executable and select your USB drive as an install location, (you will need about 85 MB free with the zero edition).
3. On your USB drive select and run `WinPython Command Prompt.exe`
4. In the resulting command prompt run `pip install Pillow qrcode colorama`
5. Wait a few seconds for the install to finish
6. You can now disconnect from the internet
7. Test with the command, in the same command prompt `qr https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/` you should get the resulting QR on in the command window.
   [image: Command Window Result]
8. You can output to a file in svg format with a `--factory=svg` flag: `qr --factory=svg https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/ > link.svg`
9. You can also create in any PIL supported format, (most image formats), with `qr --factory=pil https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/ > link.jpg`
   [image]

All of the above is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Windows Compatible
- Portable
- Offline once installed.

Of course you now also have the power of python available.

Comment: You are truly the Python master!

Answer (score 0):

i stumbled across a program you are probably interested in...
[**Portable QR-Code Generator**](https://sites.google.com/site/qrcodeforwn/home/qr-code-generator-for-wireless-networks):

- generates qr-codes from several data (simple text, URLs, eMails, vCard, WiFi, GPS)
- is a portable app packed into just one jar-file (<1MB)
- is gratis and also free as in speech (GPLv3)
- is cross platform usable as long as JRE6 or newer is installed
- why should it need internet access? - i haven't controlled it, but i doubt such a nasty behavior.

the only downside is, that its development seems to have stalled years ago... but well, it's open source and based on [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/). so if there is an essential update really necessary, it shouldn't be that hard to accomplish.